# raphael graph improper loading on tabbed ajax page

Tags: jquery, raphael, graphael, jquery-bbq

hello im using raphael line graphs on my website for stats. the graphs are located within my site's dashboard and the dashboard is jquery bbq tabbed. when you navigate to the graphs for the first time the whole graph is distorted, until you refresh the page then it looks correct. not sure whats really causing this, i think it has something to do with the way its being loaded, because if you like directly to the reports tabs then the graphs will be displayed correctly.

i have a guest account for people to sign and see whats happening.
http://nichepage.com
user: guest
password: welcome

1. sign in and go to this url http://www.nichepage.com/dashboard
2. click on the last tab, "niche reports", you'll notice the graphs aren't being displayed correctly.
3. refresh the page, and the graphs will be displayed correctly
4. try navigating to the reports tab directly http://www.nichepage.com/dashboard/#p=r

Comment: cannot reproduce on Chrome. graphs simply display zero values. what do you mean by *not correctly*?